# Roll up dataframe values into a cell above it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `grocery` as follows:

```
#Code
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

data = {'Item':['Flour', 'Eggs', 'Cabbage', 'Detergent', 'No Item', 'No Item', 'No Item', 'Tissues', 'Batteries', 'No Item', 'No Item'], 
        'Price':[10, 11, 12, 13, np.nan, np.nan, np. nan, 14, 15, np.nan, np.nan],
        'Description':['one', '', 'three', '', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', '', 'ten', 'eleven'],
        'Type':['Grocery','Grocery','Grocery','Grocery','Grocery','Grocery','Grocery','Grocery','Grocery','Grocery','Grocery']} 
  
grocery = pd.DataFrame(data) 

print(grocery)

#Output

         Item  Price Description     Type
0       Flour   10.0         one  Grocery
1        Eggs   11.0              Grocery
2     Cabbage   12.0       three  Grocery
3   Detergent   13.0              Grocery
4     No Item    NaN        five  Grocery
5     No Item    NaN         six  Grocery
6     No Item    NaN       seven  Grocery
7     Tissues   14.0       eight  Grocery
8   Batteries   15.0              Grocery
9     No Item    NaN         ten  Grocery
10    No Item    NaN      eleven  Grocery
```

What set of operations should I perform to merge/roll up the description column contents placed in front of `No Item` into the description one cell above it?

For example, `description` = `ten` and `description` = `eleven` in `item` = `No Item` roll up under description of `item` = `Batteries` and then the rows containing `item` = `No Item` are dropped.

Desired output below:

```
    #Desired Output

        Item  Price     Description     Type
0      Flour     10             one  Grocery
1       Eggs     11                  Grocery
2    Cabbage     12           three  Grocery
3  Detergent     13  five six seven  Grocery
4    Tissues     14           eight  Grocery
5  Batteries     15      ten eleven  Grocery
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like that?

```
df2 = (grocery
    .replace('No Item', np.nan)
    .ffill()
    .groupby('Item', sort = False)
    .agg({'Price':'first', 'Description':list,'Type':'first'})
)
df2['Description'] = df2['Description'].apply(lambda l: ' '.join(l))
df2
```

produces

```
             Price  Description      Type
Item            
Flour        10.0   one              Grocery
Eggs         11.0                    Grocery
Cabbage      12.0   three            Grocery
Detergent    13.0   five six seven   Grocery
Tissues      14.0   eight            Grocery
Batteries    15.0   ten eleven       Grocery
```

Note this assumes all the `Item`s are unique in the original list

Comment: you can use `replace('No Item', method='ffill')` instead of `replace('No Item', np.nan).ffill()` and also in the agg, you can do directly `'Description':' '.join` instead of list ;)

Comment: @piterbarg Perfect !! worked like a charm, thanks. Since the index changed to `Item`, you may want to add `as_index=False` in `groupby`. I also incorporated the suggestions made by @Ben.T , thanks.